# Ambiguous syntax for IN clause

Tags: subquery, where

I am working on some select query and I found this syntax

```
SELECT NOM
  FROM INGENIEUR A
 WHERE 7 IN (SELECT CODEPT
               FROM EMPLOI
              WHERE MLE = A.MLE)
```

I have never seen this before.

is it possible to test if an integer is in a list of values?

Normally, the clause in must verify if a column value corresponds to a list of the values of the subquery.

Comment: Would you consider `WHERE 7 IN (5,6,7,8)` to be invalid, too? ;)

Comment: I don t know. I am not understanding this syntax. The query is working fine but I not understanding how it works

Answer (score 2):

`IN` can be followed by a list of values (one or more), or a subquery returning any number of rows consisting of 1 column. These syntaxes are logically equivalent.

For example:

```
x IN (SELECT id FROM user)
```

is equivalent to providing explicitly the list of id's:

```
x IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

In both cases, IN can have any expression as lefthand operand. For example:

- A column name: `col IN (SELECT ...)`
- A number: `7 IN (SELECT ...)`
- A text: `'hello world' IN (SELECT ...)`
- An arithmetic espression: `1 - 5 IN (SELECT ...)`
- A function: `PI() IN (SELECT ...)`

In all these cases the DBMS will evaluate the expression on the left, and then the subquery. If at least one value returned by the subquery is equal to the left operand, the whole `IN` expression returns `TRUE`.

Comment: is there any good example explaining this on the net? I googled but get not a good illustrative one

Comment: @AdelEssafi - Well, there's [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/199768/116653) question and answer, now. Also, check the syntax for `WHERE` and search conditions for your DBMS (for example, for SQL Server, [`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql) and [search conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/search-condition-transact-sql)).

Comment: Since @AdelEssafi still needed examples or clarification, I extended my answer. I hope that now it is clear/exhaustive enough. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: @AdelEssafi Note that (in most DBMS) you can also compare tuples with the IN clause , e.g.  `where (a,b) in (select x,y from  ...)` or `where (1,2) in (select x,y from ..)` or `where (a,b) in (values (1,2), (2,3), (3,4))`